# Deployment and/or Registration Failed C#

Tags: c#, compact-framework, emulation, device, assembly-references

I have a Device-application (Compact Framework) in C#. When I Debug my solution I get this error:

```
Error   1   Deployment and/or registration failed with error: 0x8973190e. Error writing file   '%csidl_program_files%\hhrcv_app\system.windows.forms.dll'. Error 0x80070070: There is not enough space on the disk.
Device Connectivity Component
```

I have done some research about this and tried to remove and add the References back. Also hard reset the Emulator but still nothing.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compact Framework applications can not use Windows Forms DLLs.  What it most likely happening here is that either you are directly referencing a desktop assembly, or you are through a dependency.  That is causing Visual Studio to detect that it needs the desktop framework DLLs, which it then tries to push to the device.  Since these files are quite large, it's running out of space (though even if it had space, it would fail to run).

You need to go back to your project and remove all references to any desktop assemblies or to assemblies that might in turn reference them.

Comment: Really? Cause when I create new Windows CE project, system.Windows.Forms is added by default. And when I remove it from my project I get red errors all over.

Comment: OK, see the edit that `ctacke` made. His edit is probably closer to what's going on. ;)